# Power Apps - Click button and update/change dropdown value

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, powerapps

I have a simple SharePoint list named "Test_approval" which contains a choice column(drop-down list) named "approval_status". This choice column has 3 option "approved", "rejected" and "pending". When a new item is created the approval_status is set to "pending". I am trying to create a simple mobile app in power apps which will use a button to update the dropdown value from "pending" to "approved". In power apps my button is "button1" and the approval_status column is named approval_status_DataCard2. I am looking to add a formula the button1.onChange which runs the update and then submits the form. I know how to update a text box using the updatecontext formula "UpdateContext({textboxUpdateVariable:"Approved"})". Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this for a dropdown value ?

Comment: The approval_status column is probably named approval_status, it is the data card which is approval_status_DataCard2

Comment: Your capitalisation is irregular, and PowerApps is case sensitive.  Is the choice value 'Approved' or 'approved'?

Comment: Hi , Meneghino, thanks for your reply, yes choice value is "Approved", that was just a mistake in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you want for the OnSelect property of Button1 is

```
Patch(
    Test_approval,
    {ID: YourItemId},
    {approval_status:{
        '@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        Value:"Approved"
        }
    }
)
```

Where YourItemId is the ID of the item in Test_approval.  This will be typically be the item selected in a gallery, so could be something like:

```
Gallery1.Selected.ID
```

Comment: I will try this now , the ID of the item is 644 on the SharePoint list will i plug this value in just for test purpose ?

Comment: I have added the ID into your function but replaced the comma after Test_approval with ";" as i was getting an error. But i am getting an error at the next comma now saying "paren close found error".

Comment: i get the same error after the first comma "expected paren close , found error"

Comment: If you use US/UK locale, then use my syntax. If Italian/French/German etc. locale then all , should be ; instead.  (And by the way all ; should be replaced by ;; but there are none in the current code)